# Estimating number and volume of cells in a rat brain from a sample

Tags: estimation, sampling, biostatistics

I have a sample made of several disjoint cuboids. Within each cuboid, I have cells entirely contained in the cuboid and fragments (intersecting one or
more faces, so their total volume is unobserved). Cells are of different forms
and sizes and lie in random positions and orientations. There are in each cuboid
far more fragments than totally contained cells

The problem is to estimate both total volume AND number of cells. There is no
problem with volume, but I am struggling with the number of cells. I cannot count
fragments as one cell, for that would lead to duplicity. I cannot estimate
total volume and divide by the average volume of totally observed cells, because
this average volume underestimates the real average volume: small cells are more likely
to be totally contained in a cuboid.

I would be grateful for any pointers or ideas on how to deal with this problem.

Comment: Are these biological "cells" with discernible nuclei? Or something else?

Comment: Good point. No, not in general. I cannot rely on that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Estimating the number of cells when you only observe bounded windows is a well known problem from [**stereology**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereology).
Stereologists (in particular HJ Gundersen, under the pseudonym DC Sterio) have come up with simple counting rules that avoid counting cells or other items more than once, while ensuring that each is counted *if* the whole space is covered with windows (tessellated, i.e., no overlap).

In most cases, windows will only cover a fraction of the whole space. Then, an estimator for the total number of items is given as the total sum of counts, divided by the fraction of space covered — a Horvitz-Thompson estimator.

For 2D images, cells intersecting a rectangular window are counted if and only if they do not intersect the forbidden lines:

- a half line extending the left side from the bottom left corner upwards,
- the bottom of the window,
- a half line coming from below and ending in the bottom right corner.

[image: Counting frame for planar images]

Sketch of the counting frame rule: here, you would count two of the five cells that are visible in the observation window.

When the cells are convex, it is enough to check if the cells touch the forbidden sides of the observation window.

For serial sections, a so-called “disector rule” has been invented that takes care for three dimensional objects [(J.Microscopy, 1984)](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1365-2818.1984.tb02501.x). Here you compare the upper and lower section plane of pairwise serial sections, and count objects that touch the upper plane but not the lower plane.

Nowadays, with 3D voxel images observed in cuboids, we have a situation that relates to the two-dimensional counting frame. The cuboid has three forbidden faces that share a corner. A cell is only counted if it does not touch any of the forbidden faces. I've tried to sketch it below: for a cuboid, where the left, back and bottom face are "forbidden". In the right part, there three cells visible in the cuboid, but only one of them is counted.

[image: Three dimensional counting frame]

Left: a cuboid with three forbidden faces (hatched red). Right: three cells intersecting the cuboid, only one is counted (black), the other two (blue) touch the forbidden faces.

**Caveat**: if cells are non convex, for example have arms that can reach anywhere, you would need to extend the forbidden faces of the cuboid with forbidden half planes, analogously as in the 2D case. Otherwise cells can be counted more than once.

#### Reference recommendation

- Adrian Baddeley, Eva B Vedel Jensen (2004): Stereology for Statisticians (Chapman & Hall). This excellent book gives a thorough introduction to the mathematical background and ideas behind stereological methods, and discusses statistical implications.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is quite useful.  My problem is the 3D case. I need now to understand the rationale for the forbidden faces, although it seems quite intuitive. Would this rule also hold in the case a cell intersects BOTH a forbidden face and the opposite, non-forbidden one?  The Z dimension of my cuboids is fairly small and this happens quite often.

Comment: Yes, any cell that intersects a forbidden face is not counted. If you cover the space with cuboids, there will finally, almost surely, be one cuboid that allows the cell to be counted. I will clarify this in my answer. There is one caveat: cells that are not convex could "cheat" and have arms that they stick inside several windows or cuboids. Therefore the forbidden lines in the first sketch extend above and below.

Comment: "If you cover the space with cuboids, there will finally, almost surely,  be one cuboid that allows the cell to be counted."  Problem is the third dimension Z of my cuboids is only 70 nm, so cells with diameter larger than that will have no chance to be counted, no matter how many disjoint cuboids are taken. I would need larger cuboids, and that is beyond my power.

Comment: I have objects which are horseshoe-shaped, but not many, thnkfully.  But I have many fairly convex objects which because of their size have parts inside several cuboids --of which I only observe one.

Comment: Only 70nm in height: is it possible that cells do either hit both top an bottom or neither, due to optical effects? How large is a typical cell?

Comment: Sorry, may I correct. We have 10 slides from an electronic microscope, equi-spaced 70nm in the vertical dimension. The total depth of the cuboid is thus 700 nm.  Looking at the slides, the cross-sections in the X-Y plane are often 200-400 nm wide, yet when we digitize with a labelling algorithm to find connected voxels, there appear objects hitting both top and bottom of the cuboid.

Comment: This sounds like the “disector” method would be appropriate (the counting based on serial sections) Here is a randomly picked paper where the authors used the disector in connection with FIB-SEM: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2784681/
Should we continue discussing very specific details somehow else?

Comment: I will have a look to that paper. Thank you very much again. Your help much appreciated.